# call to php file via ajax not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This seems like a relatively simple question, and I am pretty new to using ajax, but I saw a post about being able to call a PHP script when an OnClick event has been triggered. I am trying to destroy a session upon a user clicking the "Log Out" link, so I want to call the `logout.php` file when the OnClick event has occurred. My problem is that nothing happens when the link is clicked.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Expand Panel
$("#open").click(function(){        
    //when the user clicks the logout button
    $.ajax({
        url: "logout.php"
    )};
}); 
}); 



<div class="tab">
    <ul class="login">
        <li class="left">&nbsp;</li>
        <li><?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){echo $_SESSION['username'];}else{echo 'Hello Guest!';}?></li>
        <li class="sep">|</li>
        <li id="toggle">
            <a id="open" class="open" href="#">Log Out</a>      
        </li>
        <li class="right">&nbsp;</li>
    </ul> 
</div> <!-- / top -->
```

Comment: how do you know that it's not working??

Comment: If it works, you probably still have to update the page to see that you have been logged out. Try inserting an `alert('X');` before the `$.ajax()` call and see if it displays the `X` when you click `Log Out`. Additionally, you probably want to do a `return false;` at the end of your click handler to disable your browser's default click processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you expect the output of the logout.php file to show. I think that your code might be working but that you forgot to tell the ajax where to put the data that it receives.

Try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'logout.php',
  success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert('Logout completed.');
  }
});
```

Where "result" points to the div you want to load the response into.

Comment: I am trying to redirect the user to the login screen, which is the first screen they come to when they visit the site.

Comment: Then why are you using ajax? Ajax is all about not needing to redirect/reload. I would just navigate to the logout.php and if really needed redirect to login.php in your php code.

Comment: So if I redirect the user when they click the link logout (just using a regular link back to the login screen), how to I execute session_destroy() as well when they click this link?

Comment: To do that, you could use a normal link to logout.php, where you destroy the session. Then you redirect the user back to login.php like [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php): header('Location: http://www.example.com/login.php');

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert('loaded!')
  // Expand Panel
  $("#open").click(function(){      
    //when the user clicks the logout button
    $.ajax({
      url: "logout.php"
    )};
    alert('clicked!')
  }); 
});
```

If this displays a popup saying clicked! then the event is being triggered. Tell me what happens so we can narrow it down to the $.ajax failing or the click event not being triggered.

If you are using firebug then you can go to the console panel and inspect XmlHttpRequests to closely look at any responses coming back from the remote script, if you have sent any back from the script that is.

Comment: ok i have the alert working. I had the $.ajax({ url:"logout.php"}) tags switched, but I am still not getting the php file to run. It is suppose to redirect the user but I am left on the same page after the click.

Comment: Firstly, it isn't possible to redirect a user to another page using ajax directly, hence the Assynchronous part of the AJAX acronym, you would be better off doing this entire process without ajax, using a conventional link to a php script. Second if the event is not being triggered, place an alert above the function call -- see my edit above

Comment: Redirecting is done by setting `window.location.href` in JavaScript, however, this defeats the purpose of using AJAX as others have said.

Answer (score 0):

Using $.ajax isn't the same as clicking regular links. $.ajax doesn't "follow" the link, it loads the data from that link into the document without refreshing the page.

What you need to do is do what you want in your logout.php file and then you sent information on whether logout succeeded or not. You do that by outputting HTML, XML or JSON, which you check in your javascript code and take appropriate action (redirect user, lock down the UI or whatever).