# request PHP file in wordPress using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

can i request PHP file in wordPress like "single.php" or "page.php" by ajax instead     functions.
 thanks

Comment: You cannot access the file directly through ajax, WordPress wouldn't allow you to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Try below things.. May help to focus more deeply into the reasons of why or why not..

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

[call to php file via ajax not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634776/call-to-php-file-via-ajax-not-working)

Below are for calling the php functions from AJAX

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?268187-Calling-a-PHP-function-using-AJAX-how

http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=123862

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

    $("#className").whatever({
        source: "/path/to/your/php/file.php",
        ...

    select: function(){
        ...
    }
});
```

now in that php file.php

```
<?php
require_once ("path or ../to/wp-load.php);
whatever_your_php_function_name_is();
?>
```

and finally in your php function

```
function whatever_your_php_function_name_is(){
    ...
    $data = json_encode($whatYouWant);
    echo $data
}
```

Something like this.